# UK visa- does certificate of sponsorship still necessary when your postdoc salary covered by a outside institution?

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom, visa

I got a postdoctoral scholarship from a Turkish Science Institution. It covers a monthly stipend for a year and travel expenses.
A university in the UK accepted me as a "postdoctoral fellow". The university does not pay me any salary, they just host me. The Turkish Science Institution will cover my expenses as a scholarship.

Is a certificate of sponsorship from the host UK university still necessary for a visa application? Do I need to apply for a skilled worker visa?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you have probably gotten the right answer already, but if you need more, you might want to ask on [travel.se] instead, they tend to be more knowledgeable about this sort of issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your case is a bit unusual and you may want to consult an immigration lawyer. I am not a lawyer and this is not a legal advice. The admin team in your host University is likely specialised in Study and Work visas, while your situation may require a different type of visa.

- I do not think that a Work Visa is right for you, because you are not going to work in the UK, in a sense that you will not be employed by a UK organisation and you won't receive a salary in the UK and it won't be taxed by the UK government.
- I also do not think that Study visa is right for you because you are not going to study in the UK, in a sense that you will not be paying tuition fees to the University, which the UK government can tax.

Your situation may be covered by what was previously known as a Academic Visitor Visa. It now merged under the Standard Visa type, but there are still [special instructions](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/visit-as-an-academic) for academics. Please read the link and discuss it with your host institution and perhaps also with an immigration council.

Comment: Thank you so much, this info is really helpful.  I got lost in the UKVI website for days. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is needed, as far as I know, for your visa application (you must have your sponsor on the visa I believe).

As for the type of visa, it is probably "skilled" visa, or "talent". But you have to ask your university's admin team.